# Simple logical syntax termcolor python

Tags: python

I have simple logical problem with my code. I want my console's output is blue so I import termcolor, but this the problem

```
from termcolor import colored

winner_name = "John"
result = colored((">>",winner_name,"<<"),"blue")
print(result)
```

when the code executed, the output is

```
('>>', 'John" , '<<')
```

I tried some replace funct

```
results = result.replace( "(" and ")" and "'" , "" )
```

This work but the output is

```
(>> , John , <<)
```

I Want the output is

```
>> John <<
```

Comment: `(">>",winner_name,"<<")` is a tuple.  Use a plain string:  `">> " + winner_name + " <<"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead

```
colored(f">> {winner_name} <<", "blue")
```

the variable name in curled brackets will be replaced by it's value inside the f string.

If you don't want to use f strings

```
colored(">>" + winner_name + "<<", "blue")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're constructing a tuple. You need to make a single string. There are several ways to do so. You could use `+` directly

```
">> " + winner_name + " <<"
```

or, more idiomatically, you can use f-strings.

```
f">> {winner_name} <<"
```

Comment: Exactly the same answer, but beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

It's printing the brackets because you are printing the tuple.

If you are using a newer version of python you can use f strings:

```
result = colored(f">> {winner_name} <<", "blue")
```

Otherwise you can do it like this:

```
result = colored(">>" + winner_name + "<<", "blue")
```